# Stopping a timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lmao/ffz5zuku/) that I am working on, and when my mouse leaves the textarea, it closes. But, I can't find a way to *cancel* this timer if I hover back over it. I've even tried some examples from [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp). This is the code that closes the text box --

```
function close() {
     setTimeout(function() {
       $(Img).css("transform", "rotateX(0deg)");
       $(Txt).css("transform", "rotateX(90deg)");
    }, 1000);
  }

$(Txt).on("mouseleave", function() {
   close();
   $(Txt).blur();
});
```

Comment: You should set a condition. A variable that holds a value, which determines, if the timer should take action or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted from W3Schools has exactly what you need...

`setTimeout()` returns a reference value, which you can pass to `clearTimeout()` later to cancel the timer.

```
var timerID; //set outside the function

function close() {
     timerID = setTimeout(function() {
       $(Img).css("transform", "rotateX(0deg)");
       $(Txt).css("transform", "rotateX(90deg)");
    }, 1000);
  }

$(Txt).on("mouseleave", function() {
   close();
   $(Txt).blur();
});

//somewhere else do this...
clearTimeout(timerID);
```

Comment: Alright, thanks! I must have just been using it in the wrong way or something.

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout function returns you the handler which you can later use to reset the timer.

For example,

```
var myVar;

function myFunction() {
    myVar = setTimeout(function(){ alert("Hello") }, 3000);
}

function myStopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
var myTimeout;

function close() {
     myTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
       $(Img).css("transform", "rotateX(0deg)");
       $(Txt).css("transform", "rotateX(90deg)");
    }, 1000);
  }

$(Txt).on("mouseleave", function() {
   close();
   $(Txt).blur();
}).on("mouseenter", function() {
   clearTimeout(myTimeout);
});
```